# button not aligning to select form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

The button is coming below the select form.Both of them are in a column of the table.How to make button come right of the select form with a slight space in between them.

HTML:

```
 <form class='form-horizontal'>
        <fieldset  >   
            <span class='control-group' >
            <span  class='controls'>
                <select id='fl' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'>
                    <option value='1'>Option1</option>
                   <option value='2'>Option2</option>
                   </select>

            </span>
            </span>
            <div><button id='mybtn' type='button'>Save</button></div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

CSS:

```
#fl{
    padding: 3px;
    height:25px;
    font-style: italic;
    width:150px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

In the inspect element,the line "`<select id='fl' class='form-control' style='cursor:pointer;'`>`" when hovered,shows a lot of margin on the right side in the orange color inspite of setting it to 0px in my css file.

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qJ8ee/

Comment: You need to post a proper example that demonstrates the problem. Try a jsFiddle or CodePen demo.

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle demo to my problem..can you please look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#fl{
    padding: 3px;
    height:25px;
    font-style: italic;
    width:150px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qJ8ee/2/